# How to replace for loop here?

Tags: python, function, performance

I have created this function in python for generating different price combinations for a product dataset. So if a price of a product is 10$ the different possible prices would be [10,11,12,13,14,15].
For eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product_id': [1, 2], 'price_per_tire': [10, 110]})
```

My function:

```
def price_comb(df):
    K= [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    c=0
    for j in K:
        c+=1
        print('K count=' + str(c))
        for index,i in df.iterrows():
            if (i['price_per_tire']<=100):
                i['price_per_tire'] = i['price_per_tire'] + 1*j
            elif ((i['price_per_tire']>100) & (i['price_per_tire']<200)):
                i['price_per_tire'] = i['price_per_tire'] + 2*j
            elif ((i['price_per_tire']>200) & (i['price_per_tire']<300)):
                i['price_per_tire'] = i['price_per_tire'] + 3*j
            elif i['price_per_tire']>=300:
                i['price_per_tire'] = i['price_per_tire'] + 5*j
            final_df = final_df.append(i)
    return final_df
```

when I run this function the output is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2], 'price_per_tire': [10,11,12,13,14,15, 110,112,114,116,118,120]})
```

How ever its taking a lot of time (upto 2days) for 545k rows dataset. Im trying to find ways to execute this faster. Any help would be appreiciated

Comment: FYI, you should (almost) never use raw `for` loops with Pandas.  They will always be slow because they cannot be vectorized.

Comment: First, please clean up your code so that it's easier to read.  Use meaningful variable names and a clear description.  Your logic has a gap at price 200.  You're using bit logic (&) instead of Boolean (and), and ... well, this really belongs on StackExchange.CodeReview, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Overall, I recommend that you work through tutorials on PANDAS, Boolean expressions, and dict access, so that your code is more efficient and easier to read.  Also learn the `+=` operator.

Comment: Why do you call `i['price_per_tire']` so many times?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how can I make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide a working version of the code, here is not clear where *price_per_tire* comes from.

This algo is a O(N<sup>2</sup>) so the is a lot of improvement to do.

First suggestion is to avoid for loop using numpy or pandas, try to solve your problem using vectorial approach.
This means that internal loop can be refactored using mask technique

```
for x in df.iterrows():
   if x[fld] < limit:
      x[fld] = f(x[fld])
```

can be refactored:

```
mask = df[fld] < limit
df[fld] = f(df[fld])   # if f(unction) can work in vectorial
df[fld] = df[fld].map(f)  # Rolling version but slower
```

With this approach, you can speed up your code to a surprisingly fast version

Another point is that *df.append* is not a good practice, doing inline changes will be more efficient. You must create all needed columns *before* the main loop in order to allocate all required space .

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I have made the corrections..it should be working now. I dont get what fld is. Could you please clarify it by giving an example for my code. Thanks in advance Glauco

Comment: Hi Rohan, fld is the name of a column, this is a working example using masks: 
mask_minus_100 = df['price_per_tire']<=100
df['price_per_tire'][mask_minus_100] = df['price_per_tire'] + 1*j